# Elementary OS giving errors while trying to update apps

Tags: terminal, elementary-os, ppa

I have not been able to update any apps on my elementary os Hera 5.1 (via terminal or the AppCenter)

The error below shows when I go to my AppCenter to try and update my app/system

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main saucy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FFACA3F86663559C
E: The repository 'https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main saucy InRelease' is not signed.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main saucy InRelease is not (yet) available (The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FFACA3F86663559C)
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

I was able to update apps usually using `sudo apt-get upgrade` previously, but doing that now leaves this error, and nothing actually updates

```
W: GPG error: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main saucy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FFACA3F86663559C
E: The repository 'https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main saucy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elementary OS Hera 5.1 is based on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic and the repositories which are giving you errors don't have release files for Bionic.

1. [ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu](http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu) only
   has release files for Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) and Ubuntu Utopic 14.10, see [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu/dists/)
2. [download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/dists/](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/dists/) is a repository for Ubuntu Trusty (14.04)
3. [ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu](http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu) has release files for various older Ubuntu releases, but not for Bionic, see [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu/dists/)

It should be safe to remove these repositories from your sources. Then try the update again after running `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: looking under `/etc/apt/sources.list`  i can't find those repositories

Comment: Look for the files in directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Comment: i've been able to remove 2 of them but `download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/` isnt found anywhere

Comment: Try `grep -r 'download\.01\.org' /etc/apt/sources.list*`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it says that you're missing a certain public key. Retrieve the missing key. You can do this via -

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv FFACA3F86663559C
```

followed by -

```
gpg --export --armor FFACA3F86663559C | sudo apt-key add -
```

See, if it resolves your issue. If not, edit your question with the new warnings & errors

Now, you also have some obsolete sources you should remove. Open the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and comment out the lines that contain these by appending a `#` before them.

Comment: i got this `gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data` after running the first command